# ASP NET Boilerplate, Login saved in ABPSession

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm new on the asp net boilerplate framework, and i created a new mvc project multipage web application, without module zero.

I would like to use the AbpSession class that from what I understand has inside the user id that is taken over Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

However, I do not understand how to do after login, to save the user id in the Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

I've searched in the network and found several solutions, but in the AbpSession class the user id is always null.

The most optimal solution I found was this:

```
IList<Claim> claimCollection = new List<Claim>
{
      new Claim(AbpClaimTypes.UserId, "5")
};
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimCollection);
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

It's the first time I use principal and identity and despite being documented I did not quite understand how to use them with asp net boilerplate, and I did not find sample codes.

Do you know how to tell me the right way or tell me where to find some functional codes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Start expanding AbpSession
The last section has cleared the way of thinking. Let's roll up our sleeves and expand in this section.
AbpSession attributes have been injected into three base classes: Application Service, AbpController and ABP ApiController.
So we need to extend AbpSession at the domain level, which is the project at the end of. Core.
Now suppose we need to extend an Email attribute.

1. Extending IAbpSession
   Locate the project at the end of. Core, add the Extensions folder, and then add the IAbpSession Extension interface inherited from IAbpSession:

   `namespace LearningMpaAbp.Extensions
   {
       public interface IAbpSessionExtension : IAbpSession
       {
           string Email { get; }
       }
   }`
2. Implementing IAbpSession Extension
   Add the AbpSession Extension class, which is based on Claims AbpSession and implements the IAbpSession Extension interface.

   ```
    namespace LearningMpaAbp.Extensions
       {
        public class AbpSessionExtension : ClaimsAbpSession, IAbpSessionExtension, ITransientDependency
           {
               public AbpSessionExtension(
                   IPrincipalAccessor principalAccessor,
                   IMultiTenancyConfig multiTenancy,
                   ITenantResolver tenantResolver,
                   IAmbientScopeProvider<SessionOverride> sessionOverrideScopeProvider) :
                   base(principalAccessor, multiTenancy, tenantResolver, sessionOverrideScopeProvider)
               {}

           public string Email => GetClaimValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

           private string GetClaimValue(string claimType)
           {
               var claimsPrincipal = PrincipalAccessor.Principal;

               var claim = claimsPrincipal?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == claimType);
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(claim?.Value))
                   return null;

               return claim.Value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs

```
//Override CreateAsync method to add your custom claim
public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(User user)
{
    var claim = await base.CreateAsync(user);
    claim.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.EmailAddress));
    return claim;
}
```

3. Replace the injected AbbSession attribute
   First replace the injected ABP Session in AbpController
   Locate. ApplicationxxxControllerBase:AbpController. CS and inject IAbpSession Extension with attributes. Add the following code:

//AbpSession Hiding Parent Class

```
public new IAbpSessionExtension AbpSession { get; set; }
```

Replace the injected ABP Session in Application Service
Locate. ApplicationxxxAppServiceBase.cs. Introduce IAbpSession Extension with attributes, and add the following code as well:

```
//AbpSession Hiding Parent Class
public new IAbpSessionExtension AbpSession { get; set; }
```

Chaneg the injected ABP Session in Views AbpRazorPage
Locate. ApplicationxxxRazorPage.cs. Introduce IAbpSession Extension with attributes, and add the following code as well:

```
[RazorInject]
public IAbpSessionExtension AbpSession { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Altough the question is very general, i would like to share you some code about how to add custom field to AbpSession in ASP.NET Core.

**MyAppSession.cs**

```
//Define your own session and add your custom field to it
//Then, you can inject MyAppSession and use it's new property in your project.
public class MyAppSession : ClaimsAbpSession, ITransientDependency
{
    public MyAppSession(
        IPrincipalAccessor principalAccessor,
        IMultiTenancyConfig multiTenancy,
        ITenantResolver tenantResolver,
        IAmbientScopeProvider<SessionOverride> sessionOverrideScopeProvider) : 
        base(principalAccessor, multiTenancy, tenantResolver, sessionOverrideScopeProvider)
    {

    }

    public string UserEmail
    {
        get
        {
            var userEmailClaim = PrincipalAccessor.Principal?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Application_UserEmail");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmailClaim?.Value))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return userEmailClaim.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

**UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs**

```
//Override CreateAsync method to add your custom claim
public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(User user)
{
    var claim = await base.CreateAsync(user);
    claim.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("Application_UserEmail", user.EmailAddress));
    return claim;
}
```